# Reason for serializing a Http response

Tags: http, serialization, tcp, protocols, httpresponse

Can I assume that the reason for serializing a json Http response to byte string, is so that, the byte string could be transferred as byte stream over the underlying TCP transport layer protocol used by the Http.

Comment: The wording is wrong. This is not about *"serializing a json Http response to byte string"*. This is about a) serializing structured information as plain text (i.e. json) and then b) transferring this plain text from utf-8 encoded string into bytes and then c) using these bytes inside a HTTP response. And yes, the reason to do all of this is that a HTTP response can only consist of bytes and this is because the underlying layer is (TCP/IP, maybe TLS in between) is only capable of transferring bytes and not structured data.

Comment: Thanks Steffen for your clarification. I was trying the keep the question short and simple, and meant to say the reason for serializing a JSON format string to byte string used by the Http response.